# how to get tow template in string in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

hi i have one string like this code

```
Questions that may already have your answer 107.755.741332.1 Questions that may already have your answer 117.700.741372.1
```

how to get `107.755.741332.1` and `117.700.741372.1` with sql query?
thanks for read my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL to pull decimal values from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563877/t-sql-to-pull-decimal-values-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `string_split()` function such as the one in SQL Server 2016+ (or a version on the web).

You can then do:

```
select ss.substr
from string_split(@str, ' ') ss(substr)
where substr like '%.%.%.%' ;
```

However, SQL is not best suited for this type of string processing.